# Using Angular2 to authenticate against Azure AD

Tags: angular, adal.js

I am using Angular2 and want to authenticate the user against an Azure AD.  I found ADALjs but they cater for Angular1 only, I also found this https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-adal#adalService, but this seems still in the initial stages.  What is the best path I can take to implement this, can someone provide a working example.

Comment: There exists a similar (answered!) question on stack overflow: [How to load adal.js in webpack inside Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40044892/how-to-load-adal-js-in-webpack-inside-angular-2-azure-ad)

Answer (score 2):

This answer is probably super late, but since you asked for an example, I have modified the latest Angular 2 Quickstart and integrated ADAL into it, here: https://github.com/ranveeraggarwal/ng2-adal-QuickStart

It also has routing and protected routing.

This uses systemjs and I am yet to find a webpack-based solution.

Comment: any news on that webpack solution?

Comment: Good to see it is using the new router instead of the deprecated one.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you will need to do a number of things:

```
npm install adal-angular --save        (=>"@types/adal": "^1.0.22")
npm install @types/adal --save-dev     (=>"adal-angular": "^1.0.12")
npm install expose-loader
```

With those packages installed, you have to do the following: 
inside your component.ts:

1. write a triple slash to import the typings
   `/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/@types/adal/index.d.ts" />`
2. import adal.js and expose it as AuthenticationContext using the expose loader
   `import 'expose?AuthenticationContext!../../../node_modules/adal-angular/lib/adal.js';`
3. declare a variable of type AuthenticationContextStatic and assign it value of AuthenticationContext
   `let createAuthContextFn: adal.AuthenticationContextStatic = AuthenticationContext;`
4. Now you can initialize the authentication context using the createAuthContextFn
   **`let config: adal.Config = {  clientId : 'test' };
   let context = new createAuthContextFn(config);`**

> [How to load adal.js in webpack inside Angular 2 (Azure-AD)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40044892/how-to-load-adal-js-in-webpack-inside-angular-2)

Comment: Is there anything tricky to getting this working in a system.js environment?

Comment: @hannes  How do we expose external API's endpoints using this approach ?

Comment: You mean connect to your AD tenant? Fill in the url, no? Anyways, another approach if you use typescript, you can also try npm installing adal-ts. The repo also has a live demo hosted on azure to get you started.